# Google cloud reCAPTCHA Enterprise showing invalid argument error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python-requests, recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

devs.

I am migrating my Recaptcha V2 to the Recaptcha enterprise using the below link.

https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/using-features

the frontend integration part work and the Recaptcha checkbox part are showing.

On the backend side after the user submit the form passing the Recaptcha test. to verify the Recaptcha test, I call google REST API to create an assessment.

I am using this link.
https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-assessment#rest-api

code of the function to verify user response.

```
def verify_captcha_response(self, recaptcha_response):
        """
        Verify the Google Recaptcha V2 response of the request
         - if recatacha response value is more than the value set 
           on google recaptcha admin.
         - if request fail error will be raise and no response will be accept
        """

        if not recaptcha_response:
            return False

        if isinstance(recaptcha_response, list):
            recaptcha_response = recaptcha_response[0]

        url = "https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%s/assessments?key=%s" % ("Project id", settings.RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY)
        recaptcha_secret_key = settings.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        data = {
         "event":{
           "token": recaptcha_response,
           "siteKey": recaptcha_secret_key,
           "expectedAction": "login"
          }
        }    
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers,
                                 data=data)

        result = response.json()

        if not result['success']:
            if 'timeout-or-duplicate' in result['error-codes']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(msg.RECAPTCHA_FAILED)

            return False

        return True
```

The response I am getting.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

but as per the documentation, I am passing all the arguments.

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: API_KEY and SITE_KEY are not the same keys. You are using a SITE_KEY for the API_KEY. https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/set-up-non-google-cloud-environments-api-keys